# MySQL - Does IN() function require full TABLE scan?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey Guys, I am doing a social networking site that requires a good bit of queries. I am using 1 query that has a IN() function in it. I am wondering if this requires a full DB scan. I am not sure of any other way to get the same results.

Example Table:

```
ID | NAME | AGE
05 | Quinton | 25
22 | Stevey | 33
78 | Rebecca | 22
90 | Michael | 26

Query: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN(05,78) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2"
```

Is this the most efficient way to get a list of users that are in a array? (using PHP)

Comment: `full DB` scan or `full Table` scan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general IN does not need a table scan. If you have an index on the `id` column MySQL will be able to use that index. But when you have only 4 rows in your table it is usually fastest to perform a table scan so when testing on a small amount of data you may find that the index is not being used until you insert more data.

Comment: lol thanks, the table will be in the 100's of thousands. And the column that is seeking through is indexed. So just for clarification this IS the most efficient way?

Comment: @qrpike: Yes, that should be fine. If you want to be sure, try running `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and check what key is actually being used, if any.

Comment: Where does he miss quotes? Cause I'm desperately trying to figure out where and can't find the spot!

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't require a db scan if you have an index on the ID field.  I am assuming that the ID field is the primary key which would mean it is indexed by default.

Comment: I meant TABLE scan sorry. There is about 100k rows in the table, and the column is indexed.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an additional `WHERE` statement speeds things up. As they are evaluated from right to left a limitation to the lowest/highest id might be beneficial e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in(13,18,3456) AND id >= 13 AND id <= 3456
```

(presuming column id is indexed)

Comment: I will definitely do that! Thansks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is error in Query, it should be

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN(05,78) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2"
```

Second thing, when u r using `limit 0,2` then why u scan a full table, u can  search like this

`WHERE id=05 OR id=78 ORDER BY RAND ()  LIMIT 2`

Comment: It was just a sample query, not the one in the site.

Comment: and btw, the query doesnt need ' ' around the values.